# In android how to distinguish the register notification or the System notification?

Tags: android

As we all know, in android when u registered a broadcast, it will send a broadcast to the the BroadcastReceiver, the send count is belong to the intent action count, how i distinguish the registered broadcast and system broadcast?

Comment: What, exactly, is a "registered broadcast"? What, exactly, is a "system broadcast"?

Comment: eg: when u regiter WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION the broadcast will receive the notification immediately i called it registered broadcast, if u set the wifi disabled the system will send a broadcast, i call system broadcast! sorry, i do not know the normal name!

Comment: when you register to receive a broadcast action, you will notreceive it immediately! you will receive it when it occurs.

Comment: i test it, it will receive immediately when i register!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when u regiter WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION the broadcast will receive the notification immediately i called it registered broadcast

If the criteria you are concerned about is the "receive the notification immediately" part, that is because it is a sticky broadcast, and so you will receive the last-broadcast `Intent` for that action immediately, in addition to future broadcasts while you are registered.

> how i distinguish the registered broadcast and system broadcast?

If you mean "how do I distinguish when I get the first 'sticky' broadcast versus later ones", ideally your code does not care about this. I would consider that to be a code smell.

If you are absolutely certain that you need to handle the first broadcast differently, use a `boolean` to track whether or not a broadcast is the first one.

Comment: why i test it will alway receive the "sticky" broadcast, the count is belong to the filter action count!